# How to use webhook on Blockfrost?

Tags: blockfrost, cardano-address

I want to trigger a function when someone sent ADA to an address addr1xxxxxx.
I use webhook from Blockfrost. I see this link (https://blockfrost.dev/docs/start-building/webhooks/using-webhooks) to describe how to use it.
I works fine if I use public webhook site (https://webhook.site/)
but it fails to trigger on my own server.

I set up as follows:

1. I create a webhook on blockfrost website as follows.

- The endpoint URL is set to the static address of my server, at port 6666.
- Trigger condition is set when someone sends ADA to the address addr1xxxx

After creating this, Blockfrost will generate an Auth token.

2. I replace SECRET_AUTH_TOKEN in the following script by the above Auth token.

```
# Example of Python Flask app with /webhook endpoint
# for processing events sent by Blockfrost Secure Webhooks
from flask import Flask, request, json
from blockfrost import verify_webhook_signature

# You will find your webhook secret auth token in your webhook settings in the Blockfrost Dashboard
SECRET_AUTH_TOKEN = "SECRET-WEBHOOK-AUTH-TOKEN"

app = Flask(__name__)

# Define endpoint /webhook that accepts POST requests
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Validate webhook signature
        request_bytes = request.get_data()
        try:
            verify_webhook_signature(
                request_bytes, request.headers['Blockfrost-Signature'], SECRET_AUTH_TOKEN)
        except SignatureVerificationError as e:
            # In case of invalid signature verify_webhook_signature will raise SignatureVerificationError
            # for easier debugging you can access passed header and request_body values (e.header, e.request_body)
            print('Webhook signature is invalid.', e)
            return 'Invalid signature', 403

        # Get the payload as JSON
        event = request.json

        print('Received request id {}, webhook_id: {}'.format(
            event['id'], event['webhook_id']))

        if event['type'] == "transaction":
            # process Transaction event
            print('Received {} transactions'.format(len(event['payload'])))
            # loop through the payload (payload is an array of Transaction events)
            for transaction in event['payload']:
                print('Transaction id: {}, block: {} ({})'.format(
                    transaction['tx']['hash'], transaction['tx']['block'], transaction['tx']['block_height']))

        elif event['type'] == "block":
            # process Block event
            print('Received block hash {}'.format(event['payload']['hash']))

        elif event['type'] == "delegation":
            # process Delegation event
            print('Received {} delegations'.format(len(event['payload'])))
            # loop through the payload, payload is an array of objects with fields: "tx" (an object) and "delegations" (an array)
            for transaction in event['payload']:
                for delegation in transaction['delegations']:
                    print('Delegation from an address {} included in tx {}'.format(
                        delegation['address'], transaction['tx']['hash'])
                    )

        elif event['type'] == "epoch":
            # process Epoch event
            print('Epoch switch from {} to {}'.format(
                event['payload']['previous_epoch']['epoch'], event['payload']['current_epoch']['epoch']))

        else:
            # Unexpected event type
            print('Unexpected event type {}'.format(event['type']))

        return 'Webhook received', 200
    else:
        return 'POST Method not supported', 405



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=6666)
```

3. I run the script on my own server. My server has static as same as set in Endpoint URL
   [image]

But when addr1xxx received ADA, the script was not trigger. I do not know where I am wrong.

I am new to webhook. Your help would help me a lot.Thanks

Comment: If it works on the public side, it probably a problem with your script. When you go to the Blockfrost dashboard and click on your webhook, what do you see in `Failed requests`?

Comment: The script is copied from here ( https://blockfrost.dev/docs/start-building/webhooks/using-webhooks.) with no change except the "SECRET-WEBHOOK-AUTH-TOKEN".
In "Failed request" of the dashboard, It says "Timeout awaiting 'request' for 5000ms". I think it could not reach my public website. But I dont know how to set it.

Comment: Yeah, it appears your website is not public. Firewall? Not listening on correct interface? Can you reach it from outside of your server?

Comment: yes. My site has public IP and domain. I can access it through Internet through port 80.

Comment: What do you mean on different port? If you go to https://portchecker.co/, put in the same IP and port you have put in your webhook, is it open?

Comment: Should I config URL endpoint in the dashboard is http://xxxxx:6060/webhook or just http://xxxxx:6060. I actually do not fully understand the script.

Comment: Definitely /webhook, as it says in the comment `Define endpoint /webhook that accepts POST requests`.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Should I set the endpoint by the domain or IP address (of my server), or either of them is fine?

Comment: Ether is fine, it just needs to resolve correctly.

Comment: Thanks for quick guide. I will check the port and report later.

Comment: It works. Thanks for your support

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem has been on end-user's network configuration and not related to Blockfrost.